# jQuery UI Tabs 'beforeLoad' event is not triggering

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI Tabs, and the tabs need to be lazily loaded. But I would like to do a slight change in the url before loading.

Checking the documentation, it looks like [beforeLoad](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeLoad) is exactly what I was looking for, but I cannot make it trigger, as you can see in this example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/echo/html">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="/echo/html">Bar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeLoad:function(e,ui){
      alert(1); // never happens       
    },
    show: function( e,ui ){
        $( ui.panel ).html('<p>Loading...</p>');
    }
});​
```

Live demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/5NAKN/

Why is it not triggering?

I am using jquery-1.7.2.js and jquery-ui-1.8.11.js.

Cheers.

Comment: "Triggered when a remote tab is about to be loaded"

Comment: Then it should trigger in both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'beforeLoad' event belongs to jquery ui 1.9

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/5NAKN/28/

```
relevant, formatted code inline. umadbro?
```